# Adding bold style to outputText seems not to work

Tags: css, html, table, outputtext, apex-param

I'm using a custom table that replicates the design of a pageblockTable. Using `th` will output the text in a bold style.

Code Snippet:

```
<table id="pageblockTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MMMM}">
                <apex:param value="{!DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), IF((MONTH(TODAY()) -1) = 0, 
                                                            12,
                                                            MONTH(TODAY()) -1),
                                                            DAY(TODAY()))}" /> 
            </apex:outputText>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

This will show as this:

[image: bolded header]

Unfortunately the outcome is this:

[image: unbolded header]

I tried to overwrite it using css to force the bold style, however it does not work. I know doing something like this: `<apex:outputText style="font-weigth:800" value="August" />` will work, but I do not like this. How am I able to fix this?

Comment: By default, `th` elements are rendered in bold style. If this does not happen, there seem to be some settings interfering, a global CSS reset perhaps. Can you provide a demo of generated HTML and CSS that creates the problem?

Comment: If I'm using ID along the tag name, and ID has the highest priority how come it creates a conflict? there is nothing wrong it works fine, however if you use `<apex:outputText />` its output text won't become bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own CSS class that will make all TH's in a certain table bold:

```
#pageblockTable th {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

This CSS applies to all TH elements that are children of the elemen with ID pageblockTable.

Comment: oh! haha! I forgot the `!important`. it's working fine now. :-)